# Are "Cholent Eggs" Fleishig?

Tags: shabbat, meat, eggs

A "Cholent Egg" is a whole egg (w/ the shell) that is left in the Cholent overnight. Let's assume we have a cholent egg that is cooked in a cholent containing meat or chicken (i.e. not pareve).

Normally foods that are cooked together with meat attain a certain status as "meaty" (i.e. the taste transfers so that the fleishig taste goes into the pareve items which give it a level of meaty status). For example, if a potato is cooked in this Cholent, it has a meaty status even if subsequently removed from said Cholent.

So if we boil it down (pun intended), my question is: is a cholent egg like a potato cooked in Cholent, or does the shell somehow protect the egg's status?

Comment: According to Maran they would be considered Pareve IIRC.

Comment: What do you mean by "Fleishig status"? You certainly can't cook it with milk, but you almost certainly can eat pizza with the cheese peeled off after it, unlike after regular meat.

Comment: @DoubleAA Can you provide that as an answer with a source? The currently accepted answer would disagree with your premise. I will clarify the question, though...

Comment: The current answer has no source and doesn't clarify what it means by fleishig. Nowadays most average joes treat anything related to meat the same as a steak, but halakha has more nuanced categories, for waiting or washing before and after, and cooking in other foods or dishes.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the answerer understood the question the way it was intended (even though I admit it was written poorly). The intent of the question was to clarify whether there is a distinction about this particular item vs. all other items without shells. And the way I read the answer below, it says - shells are porous - i.e. there is no reason to differentiate an egg.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think you should reopen the question just marked as duplicate to this question. This question discusses an egg cooked with meat, the question just marked as duplicate is if an egg cooked in a meat/dairy pot is considered fleishig/milchig which IS different (see YD 95:2 which talks about it, was mid-answer)

Comment: @alicht YD 95:2 doesn't address shells. The question is about shells. Not about what happens if you cook pareve in a clean gendered pot. Only after you establish that egg shells are porous do the rules of Nat bar Nat apply to eggs cooked in their shells. (You can prove from language of the case there that egg shells are porous, perhaps, but that's a separate issue from the particulars of Nat bar Nat.) Please post an answer here with a sourced answer for eggs being porous if you have one and it will help both questions since they are linked.

Comment: @DoubleAA will try to when I get a chance . Agav, the accepted answer says egg shells are porous, but doesn’t give source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is Fleishig. Egg shells are porous.

And even if it is not, pots become fleishig so why should this be different?

Comment: You are correct that they are porous enough to transfer taste.  Although it isn't as porous as their pots- see YD 86:5.