# What is an example of a "Tavshil Shel Baser"

Tags: halacha, food, cooking-bishul, meat-and-milk, shulchan-aruch

In Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah Siman 89 Sif 3 we find the following rule. According to the Machaber if one ate a "tavshil shel baser", then, in order to eat cheese afterwards, one must only wash their hands (no waiting time is required). However, the Rema argues and says that eating a tavshil shel baser is like eating regular baser (meat) and one must wait before eating cheese (whatever amount of time you would normally eat after eating baser before eating cheese).

My question is: What is a "tavshil shel baser"? What would be a "classic" example? Are there any sources or poskim that gave actual examples of what a tavshil shel baser is?

(I have always thought (as an example) for it to be the potatoes, beans, or eggs cooked in a cholent that has meat in it. However someone suggested to me that that case would have a stricter rule than discussed in the Shulchan Aruch here, since perhaps these foods have on or inside of them "residue" or "shuman" (fats) from the meat and would be then considered to be like the baser itself. However, this doesn't seem to be the case from the language of the Rema that further explains that if there was no meat in the pot that this "tavshil" was cooked in then would be muter to eat cheese afterwards without waiting (see the mafarshim that have difficult with this since seemingly this din is pashut because of nat bar nat).)

Comment: Cholent eggs don't have any residue inside them, no? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1939/759

Comment: This has got to be one https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/115186/759

Answer (score 2):

IIRC my father explained to us once in the name of his Rav, HaRav Yaakov Peres (Posek in Yeshivat Midrash Sefaradi) that for example if one had a cholent with meat but didn't eat the meat he would not be Besari according to Maran (however, of course the Rama argues and Hacham Yishak writes Yalkut Yosef 89 that our Minhag is according to the Rama here).

Answer (score 1):

[Divrei Moshe Chapter 45](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21285&st=&pgnum=111&hilite=) explains that Tavshil Shel Basar is something that was cooked with meat, has no meat present, however has a meaty flavor.

Answer (score -1):

a common practical example is something parave, cooked uncovered with fleishig in a oven.

sorry i wrote it wrong b4 i meant this.