# If the whole vessel's volume counts in 1/60, why don't we wait?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, keilim, taste

Although this is a really basic quesiton, the topic is way beyond my education, so please excuse the lack of sources, background knowledge and proper terms, and please help me improve.

I understand that items cooked in a vessel take on, to some extent, the status of that vessel. In general, we must count the whole volume of the vessel in a bitul b'60 calculation -- and usually the vessel's volume is more than 1/60 of the whole, so the vessel is not batul.

Why, then, do we [not](http://keystone-k.org/meat-meat-equipment-dairy-dairy-equipment-parve-wait-dairy-etc/), strictly speaking, have to [wait](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34562/eating-dairy-after-pareve-on-meat-equipment) after eating something that was made with meat keilim?
(It may be that we do have to wait after eating meat to eat something made on dairy keilim?)

Comment: http://etzion.org.il/en/nat-bar-nat-status-pareve-food-cooked-dairy-or-meat-pots

Comment: @IsaacMoses Thanks. So why do we have to kasher after cholov akum/pas akum?

Comment: @IsaacMoses And why would we have to wait after eating meat to eat something made on dairy equipment?

Comment: I don't know that we have to do either of those things.

Comment: SAH Pat Akum is not kosher. The leniency of nat bar nat only applies to currently kosher flavors (known as "nat bar nat de-hetera" as opposed to "nat bar nat de-issura"). cc @IsaacMoses

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you!!! OK this is the answer.

Comment: (I know this is going to confuse you further, but needing to wait is only one measure of what makes something meat. See for instance https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28612/759 and even those who are strict in some of those cases agree it's just a custom, not basic law. It is not a priori the case that everything which could create a problem with dairy causes you to need to wait. It could be that the custom has developed to be strict as if that were so, but again that is not strictly speaking the basic law.)

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks, those confusions were already part of my confusion ;)