# Kashrut- steam from meat

Tags: kashrut-kosher, utensil

If steam from a cholent pot condensed on the cover and then the liquid from the cover fell onto a pareve container, is the container now meat?

Comment: https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/oven-kosher-find-steam-aroma-factors-change-ovens-status/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does eating a parev item cooked in an oven with meat make you meaty?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59998/does-eating-a-parev-item-cooked-in-an-oven-with-meat-make-you-meaty)

Comment: To the two closure-voters citing https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59998/does-eating-a-parev-item-cooked-in-an-oven-with-meat-make-you-meaty : How is that the same question at all? One is about liquid falling from a pot lid, the other is about baking two things at the same time. Their answers may depend on the same principles, but that's for answerers to figure out: the questions are clearly different.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question will depend on at least three factors

1. Whether the liquid from the cover was hot (generally considered to be 110 degrees F, 43C) when it fell into the container - if it was cold there are no issues as taste is not transferred without heat, so one needs to wash and rinse the container with cold water
2. Whether the container is made of a material which absorbs or not?
3. If the liquid was hot and the container absorbs, whether the volume of the walls of the container are 60x the volume of liquid that fell

For a practical ruling, you need to ask a Rav since context and details matter a lot.

Comment: Who says that plastic won't absorb hot liquid? There's lots of discussion among poskim whether you can kasher plastic or not, but I don't remember opinions which say it doesn't become non-kosher. Were you contrasting plastic to other materials which would absorb when touching cold liquid, i.e. some materials may be so porous that they could physically absorb  liquids (like sponges) and not be kosherable?

Comment: @Binyomin I agree with you and edited

Comment: Potentially there's also tata gavar here

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but an important source about the state of steams and drops created from steam:

שלחן ערוך יורה דעה קח א

> אין צולין בשר כשרה עם בשר נבילה או של בהמה טמאה בתנור א' ואף על פי
> שאין נוגעים זה בזה ואם צלאן הרי זה מותר ...אם אפו או צלו איסור והיתר
> תחת מחבת אחת מגולין אסור (תוספות) אפילו בדיעבד (שם בארוך) וה"ה אם אפו
> בכה"ג פת עם בשר אסור לאכלו בחלב (ש"ד סימן ס' ומהרא"י) אבל בזה אחר זה
> אין לחוש (תשובת מיי' סוף הל' מ"א ותשובת ר"י ואו"ה) אלא אם כן הזיע
> המחבת משניהם דאז אסור אפילו בזה אחר זה ...

SH"A YO"D 108:1

> Do not roast kosher meat with non-kosher meat or meat of an unclean
> animal in the same oven, even if they do not touch one another. But if
> you did roast them, this is permitted ... If they baked or roasted a
> prohibited thing and a permitted thing under one (covered) frying pan,
> uncovered (from one another) this is prohibited even after the fact.
> The same is true if they baked a loaf of bread with meat in such a
> manner, it is prohibited to eat it with milk. But one after the other
> there is no concern, unless there was sweat from the pan in both of
> them...

I've skipped  much of the passage because it's massive, full read is advised.

Comment: YD 93:1 is perhaps more relevant

Comment: I think the case at hand is different. Here we have meat liquid falling into a parve pot - the question is what is the status of the pot

Comment: @DoubleAA Can you elaborate? It seems to me that it's quite the same.

Comment: @mbloch I agree, as I said, it's not a complete answer.