# Hard Boiled Eggs

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, cooking-bishul, eggs, yoreh-deah

I heard second hand that one can eat hard boiled eggs on pesach, even if they were cooked in a not kosher l'pesach pot (presumably non-ben yomo?). Is this true? If so, why? Would one consequently be able to use a non kosher pot year round for hard boiled eggs?

Comment: IIRC, the shell itself, being non-porous, protects the egg inside. This would imply that an egg that cracked during cooking is not to be used, however...

Comment: There is a custom to cook eggs in a special pot because of the possibility (in the past) of grain adhering to the shell from the chicken feed. There is a story of someone who called this the "chametz pot" and made the mistake of thinking that other food cooked in it became chametzdik. Perhaps this is what you are thinking of.

Comment: sounds questionable as chametz does not become bitul b'shishim

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1939/759

Comment: Let's assume that the shell is nonporous. If you put a cracked egg inside a closed metal ball in boiling water, I assume that would be a problem (or is there some nat bar nat explanation?)